# multi fields search query for elasticsearch golang

Tags: go, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have a situation where I need to do elastic search based on multi-field. For Example: I have multiple fields in my **postindex** and I want to apply condition on four these fields (i.e. `userid`, `channelid`, `createat`, `teamid`) to meet my search requirement. When value of all these fields matched then search query displays results and if one of these is not match with values in `postindex` then it display no result.

I am trying to make a multifield search query for go-elasticsearch to search data from my `post index`. For the searcquery result four field must match otherwise it display 0 hit/no-result.

Comment: Could you give some samples for the what are you searching on the fields? Maybe you can give something like : 
`userid = 1 AND channelid = 5 AND createat > 2022-01-01 AND teamid = 1` Is this what your are doing?

Comment: I think you are looking for bool query but according to your answer I will write a answer here.

Comment: @hkulekci Thank you of your response. 
This is sample like : `userid = mcqmycxpyjrddkie9mr13txaqe AND channelid = dnoihmrinins3qrm6bb9175ume AND createat > 1672909114890 OR teamid = qomrg11o8b8ijxoy8hrcnweoay`.
note: create time store in mili

Comment: In here you need to use bool query but you need to be a little bit more clear on OR part. Could you share with some paranthesis for the OOR part? Something like, `(userid = 1 AND channelid = 1 AND createat > 2022-01-01) OR (teamid = 1)`. is this right?

Comment: @hkulekci `(userid = 1 AND channelid = 1 AND createat > 2022-01-01) OR (teamid = 1)` is right one. I need to use bool query for this condition.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think you need to write a following query :

```
GET postindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "userid": {
                    "value": "mcqmycxpyjrddkie9mr13txaqe"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "channelid": {
                    "value": "dnoihmrinins3qrm6bb9175ume"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "createat": {
                    "gt": 1672909114890
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "teamid": {
              "value": "qomrg11o8b8ijxoy8hrcnweoay"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In here, there is a bool query with should in parent scope, which is like OR. And inside the should there is another bool query with must which is like AND. We can also write the query shorter, but this will be better for you to understand.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you convert it in go request/code?
@hkulekci